# number is not defined using react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using react.js and I got that error :

'number' is not defined. The error comes from that line :

```
useState<Array<number>>([]);
```

Do you know how can I do to solve that ?

Comment: It's because you're using typing inside a Javascript file. If you want to do it consider to use Typescript

Comment: do you have a tsx file or a jsx file?

Comment: can you try this ```useState<number[]>([])```

Comment: Looks like you are evaluating Typescript as JavaScript and this code happens to be valid JavaScript syntax (but doesn't at all do what you intend it to do). The issue has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Yes absolutely it is a tsx file but I want to translate in a javascript file... How can I do that ?

Comment: *"How can I do that ?"* That depends on how your build system is setup.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 const [num, setNum] = useState<number[]>([]);
```

Comment: I got `Unexpected token`

Comment: The problem is not with the OPs code itself but that they don't seem to compile to JavaScript.